# PayPal transaction buyer and merchant

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, paypal

How can I associate the ID I'm receiving after payment with the ID I see in transaction history on the PayPal website?
The id that I get in my app looks like: `PAY-0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA`
And the id I see in the record is like: `8AL6036628182933V`.
I've already had ideas about creating an invoice, but I have not been able to understand or understand the procedure.
I'm using Ionic 3